# Using calc() for positioning

Tags: css

I have a `relative`-positioned div, and want to align it using CSS3's lovely `calc()`. It's not working.

**[Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/XYrK4/)**

Apologies for messy code, just mocking up a comparable design to avoid shoving the more complex code surrounding my actual project in your faces.

For some reason, this is throwing an invalid property value error, and I can't work out why. Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's working on my browser, but anyways try using the prefixed versions just to make sure, -webkit-calc() and -moz-calc()

Comment: *sigh* Thank you so much. Due to computer issues, I'm presently operating off of a Lucid Lynx LiveCD, and apparently only an outdated version of Chromium is supported by it. Vendor prefixing: it's what's for dinner.

Answer (score 0):

A simple test you can do is:

```
left: calc(100% + 1px);
```

[image]

if you see it left 100% and just a tiny 1px space.... :D

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc <sup>(12/2013)</sup> says it all:

> This is an experimental technology
>   Because this technology's specification has not stabilized, check the compatibility table for the **proper prefixes to use in various browsers**. Also note that the syntax and behavior of an experimental technology is subject to change in future versions of browsers as the spec changes.

Comment: BTW for simple positioning use cases it's also possible to combine positioning with margin to avoid `calc()`, e.g.: `left: 100%; margin-left: 1px` will have the same effect as `left: calc(100% + 1px)` ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XYrK4/2/)), good to keep in mind when old browsers are concerned.